# Migrating from Orchard CMS to Wordpress CMS

Tags: wordpress, migration, orchardcms

I have this task at hand to move data from Orchard CMS ( that I have no clue about ) to WordPress ( that I work with for years ), I have searched for migration tools but there is hardly anything to help me on this task. If anyone had something similar to point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a direct migration tool from Orchard to WordPress so this will require some custom work.

Orchard has an export feature that you can use to extract all contents to an XML or JSON file. You can then build custom code to map that data to whatever format you need to import into WordPress. Keep in mind however that Orchard is a much more flexible CMS than WordPress and you may not be able to map all concepts, depending on what Orchard features are used and what structure the data has.

Documentation to export from Orchard 1.x can be found [here](https://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Import-Export/#export). Essentially, you need to enable the import/export feature in Orchard through its admin tool, then navigate to the export admin screen and choose the data you want to export.